# Script Control for Bar Charts in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am new to script controls using IronPython in Spotfire. I wanted to implement a functionality like this:

I have a dropdown box in Text Area with option1 and option2. and have three bar charts on the same analysis tab.

If I select option1 from dropdown then the X axis values of the bar charts should be changed accordingly and so with option2.

Please help me to understand how I can implement this using IronPython Script. What if I need to change the X axis values for a particular bar chart out of three available.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can any body help me in this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the current build of Spotfire (6.5) you can attach a script to run any time you update a document property.  I'm guessing your dropdown menu is a document property that you've set up to select specific columns.
Here are the steps to follow:

1. In a text box, insert a property control
2. Create a new document property.  Name the document property (here named xaxisproperty) and set data type to string
3. Set property value through Column Selection, then choose the data table from which columns should be selected and choose your columns using the select columns button
4. Attach a script to your document property (Select Execute the script selected below)
5. Create a new script with the following

---

*input variables need to be specified in the script parameters*

*Plot1 as the figure/visualization 1*

*Plot2 as figure/visualization 2*

*xaxisproperty: as the document property associated with the dropdown list (Set as the appropriate document property when editing the script parameters*

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import ScaleAxis

plot1= plot1.As[BarChart]()
plot2= plot2.As[BarChart]()

plot1.XAxis.Expression = xaxisproperty
plot2.XAxis.Expression = xaxisproperty
```